# How to extrude a face from a selected mesh in Babylon,js using the ExtrudeShape method?

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

I'm trying to extrude a face from a selected mesh in Babylon.js using the ExtrudeShape but can't figure out why I got flipped faces.

The bottom extrusions always comes flipped for a reason I ignore.

Since the extrudeShape method only extrudes corresponding to the xy plane, I rotate them and extrudes them but I can't figure why sometimes my normals are wrong

Here is [my code on the Babylon.js playground](https://playground.babylonjs.com/#X3UQ4P#19).